# Use .addClass() on all elements jQuery

Tags: jquery, addclass

I'm trying to add a class to all  tags after an element. That means I won't want to add a class to EVERY img-tag, but only the ones appearing after "trow1".

```
<td class="trow1"
<img src="somesite.com">
</td>
<td class="trow1"
<img src="somesite.com">
</td>
```

I can do this:

```
$("td.trow1").find('img').addClass('myClass');
```

But it will only add the class to the first img-tag.

Comment: It will add to all instances.. Looks like that is not a problem.. The problem is with the `HTML`  .. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/D4zS4/

Comment: your td tag isn't closed

Comment: One of those aha moments here

Comment: Your code should work. It's effectively the same as the proposed solutions.

Comment: Yeah my code was wrong, but it's correct on the site. My bad.
I used Gohn67's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like some malformatted HTML may be causing an issue.

`$("td.trow1").find('img')` is the 'preferred' way to load your selectors as it is actually more performant than stuffing it into one selector call (due to the sizzle engine requiring a regex to parse).

Comment: good but his jQuery code is working too, problem is in HTML ... so your answer dont solve problem

Comment: Your code is effectively the same as OPs code. `$('a b')` selects the same as `$('a').find('b')`

Answer (score 2):

Can you do something like this? I'm assuming you only have one image in the trow1 td

```
$("td.trow1 img").addClass('myClass');
```

Also as others have mentioned. Make sure your tags are closed properly. That could mess up the selectors. Notice the `>` bracket after `class="trow1"`

```
<td class="trow1">
<img src="somesite.com">
</td>
<td class="trow1">
<img src="somesite.com">
</td>
```